# How do I connect to multiple databases using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an application using Java servlets/JSP's. There are multiple clients using my app, however each client has a separate database. All the databases have the same schema. I would like to determine which database connection to use at the time when a user logs into the system.

For example client A logs in, I determine that client A belongs to database C, grab the connection for database C and continue on my merry way.

I am using JPA with Hibernate as my JPA provider. Is it possible to do this using multiple persistence units and determining which unit to use at login time? Is there a better/preferred way to do this?

Edited to add: 
I am using annotations and EJB's so the Persistence Context is being set in the EJB with @PersistenceContext(unitName = "blahblah"), can this be determined at login time? Can I change the unitName at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) Create several persistent units in your `persistence.xml` with different names.

2) Create necessary number of `EntityManagerFactory`s (1 per persistence-unit) and specify which persistence-unit should be used for concrete factory:

```
<bean id="authEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpringSecurityManager"/>
</bean>
```

3) Create necessary number of `TransactionManager` s:

```
<bean id="authTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="authEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

4) In your DAO's classes specify with which persistence-unit (and so with which EntityManagerFactory) you want to work:

```
public class AbstractAuthDao<T> { 

   @PersistenceContext (unitName = "SpringSecurityManager")
   protected EntityManager em;

    ...
}
```

5) In your service-objects specify which TransactionManager should be used (this feature is supported only in Spring 3.0):

```
@Transactional (value = "authTransactionManager", readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

   ...
}
```

6) If you have `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` in your web.xml, then specify in its init-param name of necessary EntityManagerFactory (or create several filters with correspondent init-blocks):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>authEntityManagerFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Who said the OP is using Spring? :)

Comment: To be fair, I never mentioned Spring in the original post either, the edit simply added more info, but this lead me to an answer that seems like it will be work, so it has been accepted.