# map three database in the same time

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have to map Three database on my project (Web application),using Hibernate/JPA ,so my question is how can I configure persistance.xml to support the three connections
this are my files :
 **persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JiraMapPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>DTOKpi.AssociationKpiProfil</class>  //from  database1
<class>DTOKpi.Kpi</class>                  //database1
<class>DTOKpi.ProfilUser</class>          //  database1
<class>DTOJIRA.Resolution</class>         //  database2
<class>DTOJIRA.Project</class>           //  database2
<class>DTOJIRA.Issuestatus</class>
<class>DTOJIRA.Jiraissue</class>
<class>DTOJIRA.Priority</class>
<class>DTOJIRA.Component</class>
<class>DTOJIRA.Issuetype</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jiradb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
</properties>
```

**My hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD  3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jiradb</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<mapping resource="DTOTest/issuestatus.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have found this link useful: [How do I connect to multiple databases using JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311614/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-databases-using-jpa) but I couldn't understand the second step

Answer (score 1):

If your three databases are the same I guess it will work, but if not, I think you should create a map file for each database.

Comment: hello I found the solution, I have added another <persistence-unit > for my second database :)