# Using Multiple Entity managers in DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to configure Spring+Hibernate+JPA for work with two databases ( one for write only i.e insertion & updation & other is only for retrieval.

I did some research & found these possible solutions:

- http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-jpa.jsp
- [Multiple database with Spring+Hibernate+JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902997/multiple-database-with-springhibernatejpa)
- [How do I connect to multiple databases using JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311614/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-databases-using-jpa)

But I stuck at one place & getting this error

```
No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactoryReadOnly,entityManagerFactoryWriteOnly
```

What am I doing wrong ?

### persistent.read.only.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="readOnly" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
        <class>com.demo.domain.Contact</class>  
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### persistent.write.only.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="writeOnly" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">       
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
        <class>com.demo.domain.Contact</class>  
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### mcv-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
        as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
        correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />

    <!-- Setup a simple strategy: 1. Take all the defaults. 2. Return XML by 
        default when not sure. -->
    <!-- Total customization - see below for explanation. -->
    <bean id="cnManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false" />

        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Make this available across all of Spring MVC -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="cnManager" />

    <bean class="com.demo.view.MvcConfiguringPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />


    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!--       START: Multiple C3P0 data-sources for DB instance                -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->

    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922351/can-i-use-multiple-c3p0-datasources-for-db-instance -->
    <!-- Using Apache DBCP Data Sources -->
    <bean id="dataSource" 
        abstract="true" >
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="user" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${db.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceReadOnly" 
        parent="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.readOnlyDataBaseUrl}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSourceWriteOnly" 
        parent="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.writeOnlyDataBaseUrl}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!--       END: Multiple C3P0 data-sources for DB instance              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->


    <bean id="jpaVendorProvider"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    </bean>

<!--    <bean -->
<!--        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"> -->
<!--        <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="readOnly" /> -->
<!--     </bean> -->

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <!-- defining multiple persistence unit -->
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>/META-INF/persistence.read.only.xml</value>
                <value>/META-INF/persistence.write.only.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSourceReadOnly" /> 
        <property name="dataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="readOnlyDsKey" value-ref="dataSourceReadOnly" />
                <entry key="writeOnlyDsKey" value-ref="dataSourceWriteOnly" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryReadOnly"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<!--        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceReadOnly" />      -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorProvider" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="readOnly" />
        <!-- entityManagerFactory does not specify persistenceUnitName property 
            because we're defining more than one persistence unit -->
        <!-- <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hello_mysql" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/META-INF/persistence.xml" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryWriteOnly"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<!--        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceWriteOnly" />         -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorProvider" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="writeOnly" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- Mark bean transactions as annotation driven -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadOnly" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerWriteOnly" />

    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- Setup the transaction manager -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->

    <bean id="transactionManagerReadOnly" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryReadOnly" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerWriteOnly" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryWriteOnly" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

My DAO:

```
package com.demo.dao;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.demo.domain.Contact;

//import java.util.Collections;

@Repository("ContactDAO")
@Transactional
public class ContactDAOImpl extends AppDAOimpl<Contact> implements ContactDAO {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3986253823316728444L;

    /**
     * EntityManager injected by Spring for persistence unit MYSQL
     * 
     */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "readOnly")
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryReadOnly")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * Get the entity manager that manages persistence unit MYSQL
     * 
     */
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * EntityManager injected by Spring for persistence unit MYSQL
     * 
     */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "writeOnly")
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryWriteOnly")
    private EntityManager woEntityManager;

    /**
     * Get the entity manager that manages persistence unit MYSQL
     * 
     */
    public EntityManager getWoEntityManager() {
        return woEntityManager;
    }


    // other functions goes here 
}
```

Both the databases have the same schema ( read & write ).

Comment: Can you show how the entity looks? did you add schema declaration on top of the enitity?

Comment: I haven't add any schema at top of my entity class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTA transaction manager. is answer to my question. Below are links for references.
```

- [JPA Multiple Transaction Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75700/jpa-multiple-transaction-managers)
- [Spring multiple @Transactional datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961371/spring-multiple-transactional-datasource)

& here is nice tutorial about integrating JTA with spring.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example.html

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar setup in a project here, and I think

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "writeOnly")
private EntityManager woEntityManager;
```

is sufficient, you don't need the additional Qualifier. But in my experience, you have to set the attribute on Transactional, too. So drop the Transactional annotation on the DAO class and start marking individual methods with

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManagerReadOnly")
```

and i believe the tx:annotation-driven element in the context doesn't work with multiple contexts, too.

And ideally, the whole stuff belongs into the service layer anyway, you don't want your DAOs to decide or even know which Persistence context they're called from. So you'd have a ReadContactService:

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "readOnly")
 private EntityManager em;

 @Transactional(value="transactionManagerReadOnly")
 public Contact readContact(int id) {
   return dao.findById(em, id);
 }
```

and a WriteContactService:

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "writeOnly")
 private EntityManager em;

 @Transactional(value="transactionManagerWriteOnly")
 public void writeContact(String name, String address) {
   return dao.writeContact(em, name, address);
 }
```

and a DAO that is unaware of the context. Then you need only N entity classes and you can reuse DAO methods (even writeOnly will eventually have to read from the database, trust me).

Comment: is it good practice to use persistent unit / entity manager in service layer rather than DAO ?

Comment: @Zeus: I have tried your solution , its still giving me the same error. I found this solution but am not able to get it ( regarding configuration point of view )

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961566/how-to-configure-transaction-management-for-working-with-2-different-db-in-sprin

Comment: Well it helps in cases where you want to create transactions by combining DAOs, for example. If the DAOs take care of their transactions themselves, you'd have to find a way to coax them into not doing that. Separating the transactional layer from the actual data access solves that problem. And in your case, with two databases you probably are going to need to implement a layer that carries unitName and transactional value. This layer has to be implemented twice afaik, and therefore should be thin.

Answer (score 0):

Add two classes

**ContactWrite.java**
on top declare the schema and table like below

> @Table(name = "Contact", schema="DB1")

Do the same for the other table in the DB2

**ContactRead.java**

> @Table(name = "Contact", schema="DB2")

Now use these two classes in the persistance xml files like below.

**persistent.read.only.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="readOnly" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
        <class>com.demo.domain.ContactWrite</class>  
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**persistent.write.only.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="writeOnly" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">       
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
        <class>com.demo.domain.ContactRead</class>  
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: according to you solution , if I have 'N' entities then there will be 2N entity classes. Can you please provide me logical reason for these ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is a little tedious, you may extend 2nd entity from the first one. I see some comments here http://www.coderanch.com/t/598699/ORM/databases/commit-transaction-multi-databases-schema I dont know how this can be done in JPA.

Comment: I have tried your solution , its still giving me the same error. I found this solution but am not able to get it ( regarding configuration point of view )

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961566/how-to-configure-transaction-management-for-working-with-2-different-db-in-sprin